# How to remove .svn folder on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I did

```
find . -type d -name ".svn" | xargs rm -rf
```

in shell, which printed

```
rm: cannot remove ‘./.svn’: Directory not empty,
```

so it didn't remove the folder.  How can I remove the `.svn` directory?

Comment: Is that the only error message you got? What happens if you type `rm -rf .svn` to remove just the `.svn` directory immediately under your current directory? What does `ls -l .svn` print?

Comment: Just only one error message,and  rm -rf .svn print  the same message,ls -l .svn print nothing.

Comment: Try `ls -al .svn`. Do you own the `.svn` directory?

Comment: Print two folders are `.` and `..`

Comment: Type `ls -ald . .svn`. That will show you the ownership of the current directory and of the `.svn` directory. Do you own both of them? Do you have write permission on the current directory?

Comment: I have have write permission,and i am own both of them.Actually i use root user to do that,and the user and group of the folder is `root.root`.

Comment: What does `type rm` say?

Comment: `rm -rf .svn` print `rm: cannot remove ‘./.svn’: Directory not empty`  `rm -rf *` print nothing.

Comment: Again, what does `type rm` say? (And I really hope you didn't have anything important in that directory.)

Comment: `rm: cannot remove directory: ‘.’`  There should be nothing important in that directory.

Comment: One last time: What is the output of `type rm`? I can't help if you won't answer my questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try reposting in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `type rm` output is `rm is hashed (/bin/rm)`

Comment: If `ls -al .svn` shows only `.` and `..` directories, and you haven't redefined the `rm` command, then I don't know why `rm -rf .svn` would complain that `.svn` is not empty. You might try running `rm` under `strace` to see what system call fails. In any case, since this is not a programming question, you should repost it on askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type d -name ".svn" -exec rm -rf {} \;` should work.

Alternatively you could export from the working copy and delete the original working copy.

```
$ svn export orignal-wc exported
$ rm -rf original-wc
```

Comment: "find . -type d -name ".svn" -exec rm -rf {} \;“ does not work,the same output is "rm: cannot remove ‘./.svn’: Directory not empty".